# How to remap the keyboard with the Super L + hjkl like vim arrows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm using Arch Linux, I tried using xmodmap, so I'm not getting it

[image: Layout to be configured]

- When you press Super L + h, it would be the action of the left arrow
- When you press Super L + j, it would be the action of the down arrow
- When you press Super L + k, it would be the action of the up arrow
- When you press Super L + l, it would be the action of the right arrow

Comment: you said nothing about any applications .... does that mean that you want the reassignment to be system wide?

Comment: I would like some XORG application, such as xmodmap, if possible

Comment: @jwerlley did you find a solution? I would love to be able to do this.